# Pass a value into filter_input() using variable

Tags: php, filter-input

Can anyone please explain, why do I get very strange warning:

```
filter_input() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given
```

when executing the code, that is part of my class and which seems perfectly fine:

```
public static function Input($type, $data, $filter = 'FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS')
  {
    $type = 'INPUT_' . $type;
    return filter_input($type, $data, $filter);
  }
```

In case I change it to, for example:

`return filter_input(INPUT_POST, $data, $filter);`

Then the warning goes to:

`filter_input() expects parameter 3 to be long`.

Everything works just fine if I use:

`return filter_input(INPUT_POST, $data, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);`

---

I realize that on [PHP: filter_input - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) in description it's stated:

> **Description**

```
mixed filter_input ( int $type , string $variable_name [, int $filter = FILTER_DEFAULT [, mixed $options ]] )
```

> **Parameters**

```
type
   One of INPUT_GET, INPUT_POST, INPUT_COOKIE, INPUT_SERVER, or INPUT_ENV.
```

### Questions:

1. Why it's said in manual `filter_input ( int $type ,` - when neither **INPUT_GET** nor **INPUT_POST** and etc are *INTEGERS*.
2. Is there a way to pass a value into `filter_input` using variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're supposed to use there are [*constants*](http://php.net/constants). These constants have *integer values*. So the documentation is entirely correct, `INPUT_GET` is an integer. Try `var_dump(INPUT_GET)`.

If you need to get a constant value from a string, use `constant()`:

```
echo constant('INPUT_' . $type);
```

Comment: Yes, so easy and straight-forward!! Never heard of that before!! It works as expected! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here the problem. When you concatenate 'INPUT_' with variable it bacame a string, see example:

```
echo $type = 'INPUT_' . 'POST'; // give you a string INPUT_POST

echo INPUT_POST; //give you 0
```

That's why :

```
filter_input() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given
```

Comment: sergio, thanks but I'm not sure what you have meant!

Comment: When you do this: $type = 'INPUT_' . $type; it became a string, but not a constant like  INPUT_POST.

Comment: Ah, alright! Yeah, *deceze* already explained that! +1 for an extra example!

Answer (score 0):

`INPUT_POST` and `INPUT_GET` are defined as follows:

```
/**
 * POST variables.
 * @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.constants.php
 */
define ('INPUT_POST', 0);

/**
 * GET variables.
 * @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.constants.php
 */
define ('INPUT_GET', 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, Rico! Could you please elaborate your answer, please!

Comment: See @deceze answer for a final solution. I only wanted to point out the type of the constants.